# Not all ASCII characters transcoded to wchar_t by mbstowcs

Tags: visual-c++, ascii, multibyte-functions

I looked into a number of similar questions but I can't seem to find a solution to my problem:
I am trying to convert characters from ASCII to wide characters (Windows UTF16) to print them on a window (the purpose is to capture custom character sets for an embedded application, including support for some Chinese)

When I use mbstowcs I end up having what I want except for the two lines between characters 0x70 and 0x8F (included) which I believe must correspond to the first values of multibyte characters.

When I use mbstowcs, my char s[5] is interpreted as UTF-8 which will not recognize some values as first characters - I was expecting some but not that many and I need characters such as the single and double quotes...
How do I force it to be understood as plain ASCII without changing the whole project?

I also tried with MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s, -1, ws, 0); but then I get always the same Chinese character everywhere, which does not help me much...

Note that this is test code.

```
        char        s[5] = {0, 0, 0}; // I should really need only [2]
        WCHAR       ws[5];

        SetTextAlign(hdc,TA_CENTER | TA_BASELINE);
        for (int y = 0; y < 16 * 64; y += 64)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 16 * 64; x += 64)
            {   
                mbstowcs(ws, s, 1);
                // Missing two lines of characters in the middle
                TextOutW (hdc, x+32, y+32, ws, 1);
                // TextOutA (hdc, x+32, y+32, s, 1);
                // Works fine but I need to handle multibyte characters
                s[0]++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: `When I use mbstowcs I end up having what I want except for the two lines between characters 0x70 and 0x8F (included) which I believe must correspond to the first values of multibyte characters.` So what exactly do you expect `mbstowcs` to do when given a leading byte without any trailing byte, other than fail?

Comment: `When I use mbstowcs, my char s[5] is interpreted as UTF-8` What makes you believe that? `mbstowcs` uses the system default codepage (aka `CP_ACP`), which is never UTF-8.

Comment: `I need characters such as the single and double quotes` Single and double quotes are 0x27 and 0x22, correspondingly, in all codepages. Are you saying your program doesn't print those? Earlier, you said `between characters 0x70 and 0x8F` (which itself is likely a mistake; I suspect you are off by one in your line cound, and "bad" characters are between 0x80 and 0x9F).